# How to write a OnCheckedChangeListener for a radiobutton in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently writing a Radio group in Xamarin that dynamically adds radio buttons to the group based on a answer set it gets from a DB.

I need some help with the custom listener needed in Xamarin.Android.

I call the create listener and pass it a radio button and then checked the status like this:

```
    MyListner c = new MyListner();
    c.OnCheckedChanged(rBtn, rBtn.Checked);
```

My Current Listener Code:

```
public class MyListner : CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener{

    #region IOnCheckedChangeListener implementation

    public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
    {           
        if (isChecked)
        {
            //If Checked code here
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable implementation

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        // NEED HELP HERE
    }

    #endregion

    #region IJavaObject implementation

    public System.IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            // NEED HELP HERE
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I need some guidance on how to properly implement the listener.
Anything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inherit your class from Java.Lang.Object:

```
public class OnCheckedChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Widget.RadioGroup.IOnCheckedChangeListener
{
    public void OnCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
    }
}
```

Comment: This. You dont need to implement `System.IntPtr Handle` or `Dispose` by inheriting java object!

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
           //Radio Group
            var radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
            radioGroup.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal; 

             //Declaring arrays
                int [] s_id = new int[] { 1, 2,};
                string [] s_sex = new string[] { Male, Female};

            // looping arrays to create radio button
                for (int j = 0; j < s_id.Length; j++)
                {
                    RadioButton radBut = new RadioButton(this);
                    radBut.Id = j;
                    radBut.Text = s_sex[j];

            //Radio Button Click Listener
                    radBut.Click += (sender, e) =>{
                      var radC = sender as RadioButton;
                      string radioChecked = radC.Text;
                      int radioId = radC.Id;
                      Toast.MakeText(this, radioChecked, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                   };
             //Adding Radio Button to Radio Group
                    radioGroup.AddView(radBut);
                }
```

above code will create a radio group with 2 radio buttons.

[image: Dynamic Radio button with click listener]